# Does tree object type in git internals point to the blob only or to trees as well?

Tags: bash, git, tree

I've explored a lot about the 3 commit model of the git internals and in the diagram,it's shown that tree object type is pointing to the other trees as well, but when I do 
**git cat-file -p 'sha-hash'**,
It tells that tree is pointing to the blobs only.
Please refer to the screenshot attached.
Please help me with a screenshot where tree is pointing to some other tree or tell me any use case which I may be missing.

[image: j]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a file's name is `a/b/c/f.ext` it will be stored in a commit as:

- at the level of the commit: a tree containing a subtree named `a`
- at the level of the subtree named `a`: a tree containing a subtree named `b`
- at the level of the subtree named `b`: a tree containing a subtree named `c`
- at the level of the subtree named `c`: a tree containing a blob named `f.ext`

Hence, from the top, we simply string together the *names* of each higher level tree to arrive at the file's actual name, `a/b/c/f.ext`.

None of this really matters while using the file, since the important version of the file is the one in the *index*, and that one is named `a/b/c/f.ext` (with slashes in the name).  It only matters when reading trees into the index (`git read-tree`), and when writing the index to a series of trees (`git write-tree`).

Comment: Thank you so much. I was missing this use case about the directory.

Answer (score 1):

I think @torek has explained it pretty well. Also, I would like to add on that this all storage is done in the form of SHA1 hashes, the `blob`(binary large object) stores file contents while the `trees` store, in maybe vague terms, the file name and subtrees inside of it.

[This](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects) is a pretty good guide to the internals of Git, you might as well take a look at it.

Cheers!